# How to install GNU MDK on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I have been trying to install the GNU MDK programm that simulates the MIX machine from Donald Knuth's book, TAOCP, but no results. I'm completely new to this, and I don't know where to even start, or what to do differently.

GNU MDK: https://www.gnu.org/software/mdk/.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "no results"? what exactly did you try, and what happened?

Comment: I have dowloaded the version 1.2.1, and following the instructions of the INSTALL doc, I executed the command ./configure, then make, and then make install. From these, only the first command worked, and I get different errors for make:make[2]:  *** [Makefile:376: mixgtk_mixvm.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:321: all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:257: all] Error 2.

Comment: MDK is available from the Ubuntu `universe` repository ex. https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/mdk - if you really need to build a version from source instead then please [edit] your question to include the information from your comment.

Comment: OMG, thank you!, now I have all running and working. :)